# jQuery function require() calls between .js pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I'm trying to do something. I thought it should be quite simple, but once again my head is spinning, possibly due to a missing colon or two much caffeine in my colon. Any help would be greatly appreciated ...

**main.js**

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');

const _ = require('./functions');

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( _.isNumber('test') );
});
```

**functions.js**

```
var _ = (function() {
  return {
    isNumber: function(obj) {
      return typeof obj === 'number';
    },
  };
})();
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.isNumber is not a function
```

*Possible Fix??*

```
module.exports = _;
```

*Adding the above to the base of functions.js allows the function to be called. However, this seems like an odd 'best practice', can someone please confirm.*

No matter how I try and call `isNumber` it simply won't run, find it or anything. I'm keen on using the browserify require() to pull in scripts, but perhaps I'm not quite across using it.

Cheers

Comment: I think you need to specify the .js extension as 'functions' isn't an exported  module?  `const _ = require('./functions.js');`

Comment: @83N, nah that's all good, it definitely finds the file, I've dropped some `console.log()` calls in there, it's solid. Thanks tho ...

Comment: Remove the trailing comma. No need to wrap in a IIFE, just assign an object to the `module.exports`. Did you see if it works without `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using it in your `main.js` file, the export would need to be an object (and yes, you need to `export` something if you want to `require` it elsewhere).

```
var _ = {
        isNumber: function(obj) {
            return typeof obj === 'number';
        },
    };

module.exports = _;
```